# Method called at __init__: make it functional (and hence a static method) or not (and a standard method)

Tags: python, class, static-methods

I'm interested in criteria for deciding between the following two types of design:

How I did it now (simplified):

```
class CommentThread(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.req = requests.get(url)
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.req)
        self.graph = self.parse_thread(self.soup)

    @staticmethod
    def parse_thread(a_soup):
        raise NotImplementedMethod("subclasses should implement this!")

class CommentThreadType1(CommentThread):
    def __init__(self, url):
        super(CommentThreadType1, self).__init___(url)

    @staticmethod
    def parse_thread(url):
        # actual implementation
        a_graph = nx.DiGraph()
        # add nodes, edges and attributes to a_graph
        return a_graph
```

And this is an alternative I'm considering

```
class CommentThread(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.req = requests.get(url)
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.req)
        self.graph = nx.DiGraph()

class CommentThreadType1(CommentThread):
    def __init__(self, url):
        super(CommentThreadType1, self).__init___(url)
        self.parse_thread(self.url)

    def parse_thread(self, url):
        # add nodes, edges and attributes to self.graph
```

In terms of functionality both approaches work equally well. What I'm interested in is if there are good reasons to prefer one approach to the other.

The only considerations I see are the following:

**Option 1:** pro: big_method is purely functional, conceptually big_method is really a static method (it does the same thing in all instances); contra: parent class has not implemented (abstract) method

**Option 2:** pro: shorter, contra: a method with side-effects

Are there any other important conceptual or stylistic considerations that may flip the balance in either direction?

Comment: There a few errors in your code, enough to make your question unclear. Please include a version of *running* code (with stubs).

Comment: Some edits made to make it clearer what I'm talking about.